# Transfer Data Using BLE with same application with in different android device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to transfer data from android phone to each other through my application using BLE. When a device comes near to me and my application is already installed in it, So my phone will establish a connection and send some data in strings and also receive from that device without notify user. Is it possible to do with BLE and I have studied BLE from

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le

But I am new so I dont know from where to start and what should i have to do?  Kindly let me know about BLE more easy for my better understanding and refer me some tutorials where I can learn that how will fulfill my application functionalities.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest starting with the Central-Peripheral example. Here you have an simple application:

https://github.com/itanbp/android-ble-peripheral-central

And tutorial with basis:

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-on-android-part-1/

In the case you described, if there are not defined roles for the android phones (master, slave), the program will have to work in alternately in two modes: central and peripheral.

This is possible form the BLE side. However, there may be a problem with the application wroking as a background service. Since Android 8 there are new restrictions and limitations in background sericves:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Bluetooth Low Energy on Adnroid is very troublesome technology. A lot depends on the version of Android, processor and antenna system of the phone.

Comment: Hey , thanks for your response. I am working on it and I will let you know if i will find some difficulty.